# Nextflow access/download S3 files and directories

Tags: amazon-s3, groovy, nextflow

I've got the following S3 resources:

```
s3://mybucket/genome/fasta/hg38.fa
s3://mybucket/genome/blastdb/  # Multiple files
```

I need to download and stage them in nextflow and access them in the python script. I've been able to make it work for the file but not for the path:

```
genome_fasta=file("s3://mybucket/genome/fasta/hg38.fa"),
blast_db=file("s3://mybucket/genome/blastdb/"),
ENV_GENOME_FASTA=genome_fasta.getFileName().toString(),
ENV_BLASTDB=blast_db.getFileName().toString(),
```

Both `ENV_` variables are set as enviroment variables and then retrieved in python script.

My problem is, when calling the nextflow process, the python code finds correctly the fasta file but notthe files under the `BLASTDB` path.

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There's nothing super special about directory paths. Nextflow will stage these in the same way it stages file paths (using the `stageAs` directive). I wonder how is your Python code looking for the files in this directory? You mention the `BLASTDB` path is ued, but you might mean `ENV_BLASTDB`? In any case, please include some code that produces the error - thanks!